# RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship [userStories] on model [App\User]

Tags: php, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have created a relationship between `User` model and `StoryModel`. But it give me the Error:-

> Call to undefined relationship [userStories] on model [App\User].

May be I'm missing something. Following is my code which I'm using

[image: Error image here]

`User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notification;
use App\CheckIn;
use App\Travel;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\NewInterest;
use App\UserStory;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = "users";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname','lastname', 'user_id','email',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function userStories(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserStory::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

`Controller Logic`

```
$usersStories = User::with('userStories')
                            ->select('id','user_id','stories')
                            ->get();
 print_r($usersStories);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wriiten mapping code in your `UserStory Model` that should be

```
public function userAccount(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

If you already written this code then check you column names in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by changing the sequence like this:

```
 $usersStories = User::->select('id','user_id','stories')
                       ->with('userStories')
                       ->get();
 print_r($usersStories);
 exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your model and try:

**User model**

```
public function userStories(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserStory::class);
    }
```

**UserStory model**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

Comment: No luck, FYI i am using the mongoDB with laravel.